# Offline Spacewalk Server - Create Repo

Tags: centos, centos7, spacewalk

I have a CentOS7 server running Spacewalk 2.6

This server manages multiple other centOS servers on a closed loop network. These are not allowed to touch the internet.

To add packages to the Spacewalk server, I must download to a USB HDD and move them over manually.

My question is, how do I create a repo under a channel that points to local storage (since I don't have a Repository URL) and is there a default location on the file system that packages should be placed / stored?

Comment: Simply adding a `file://` URL doesn't work?

Comment: Ah that's it. that works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make local package directory as a Local Repo : Use createrepo command
2. install FTP/HTTP to create a link which can be pointing from spacewalk Channel Repo.

Eg: ftp://10.80.10.199/pub/centos6.